# RatingBar customization with each rating element of increased size

Tags: android, customization

I know that I can apply my own style and swap the ratingbar star image with something else.
I need a bit more complicated thing: each ratingbar element should be larger than previous.

Take a look at the image:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

we can extend the Rating bar, keep the height of the bar proportional to the tallest star and in the onDraw set the height of each star.

this looks some place to start. [StarBar](https://gist.github.com/558283)

this link was interesting as well, though it only solves the swapping of drawables part. [LINK](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd think about own RattingBar, it would be linear layout, and in it a I would create views that has proper size. On increasing rate I would be adding more childs, and scale child views. Looks easy, probably not most efficient way, but still very flexible.